# Passing parameters from github to Jenkins on push

Tags: github, jenkins

We use an internally hosted github server for our SCM, Jenkins for our CI and Git-Flow (via maven's jgitflow plugin) for our branching strategy.

I have a Jenkins build job set up such that it takes the git branch as a parameter and then can check-out and build the correct branch based on what was selected.

[image: Jenkins Job with branch variable] 
.....

.....

.....
[image: Branch configuration]

What I would like - is to automatically trigger the BASE_JOB to build only the branch that's been pushed.  So far, I have been unable to find any way to do this.

If I set up to build when changes are pushed to github, then the job will simply rebuild whatever the last built branch was regardless of the branch that's been pushed.

I've seen some plugins for Jenkins that will auto-generate template jobs when new branches are created - but I think it is over-kill to necessitate having a job per currently active branch.

[image: My available build triggers]

Is there a way to pass a branch parameter to the "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub"? Or some other way to work around this apparent limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any pattern for the branches that will be pushed? Like a keyword / is it okay for you to build for any branches apart from mater branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with these settings and see if it works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Leaving the branch specifier blank was the way to get ALMOST what I wanted.  In your build triggers, I actually selected the "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling".  This is the one that allows the job to trigger when something is pushed to git.

Comment: The above solution required me to have only 2 build jobs.  The first I call "AUTOBUILD" - this has the branch specifier as blank and has the GitHub hook build trigger.  This job runs whenever someone pushes to git and automatically builds their branch. My 2nd job is just my usual build job that has a BRANCH variable that a user can set.  This allows the user to manually build a branch if needed.